# How to calculate DFT of signal which occurs from 3 to 8?

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, fourier

How can I calculate discrete fourier transform of this signal?

[image]

[image]

I'm confused as in the normal cases signal always start from 0 to N-1 but in this case it starts from 3 to 8 instead.

[image]

So what would be N and signal here?

```
N = 6 and signal = {3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

or

```
N = 9 and signal = {0,0,0,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

Comment: By convention, DFT is always stated as **N-point DFT** to indicate the number of samples included in the DFT frame as $n \in [0 , N-1]$. You must have been given this N to make the DFT computable. Otherwise, the best guess is to assume N = 9 in your case.

Comment: @Fat32 I see. N is not given in this exercise. So if N = 6 then the data would be {0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 5}?

Comment: yes, if N = 6 were given, then you would discard the rest of the input data (by assuming them as zero) out of the frame $ 0 \leq n \leq 5 $

Comment: If the creator of this problem didn't specify $N$, then shame on that person. That means you have to guess what is the input sequence. (That is, are the leading and trailing zero-valued blue dots part of the input, or not?) My guess is that $N=11$.